# Apply a JQuery Script to specific grid views

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, asp.net, gridview

I am struggling to apply a JQuery script to certain Gridviews on my page, The problem being that currently the script is applied to every Gridview on the page and I need to somehow specify what grids it apply's too.

The Script I am using is as follows. Author: Ryan Zielke.

```
$.fn.tablePagination = function (settings) {
    var defaults = {
        firstArrow: (new Image()).src = "./images/first.gif",
        prevArrow: (new Image()).src = "./images/prev.gif",
        lastArrow: (new Image()).src = "./images/last.gif",
        nextArrow: (new Image()).src = "./images/next.gif",
        rowsPerPage: 5,
        currPage: 1,
        optionsForRows: [5, 10],
        ignoreRows: []
    };
    settings = $.extend(defaults, settings);

    return this.each(function () {
        var table = $(this)[0];
        var totalPagesId = '#' + table.id + '+#tablePagination #tablePagination_totalPages';
        var currPageId = '#' + table.id + '+#tablePagination #tablePagination_currPage';
        var rowsPerPageId = '#' + table.id + '+#tablePagination #tablePagination_rowsPerPage';
        var firstPageId = '#' + table.id + '+#tablePagination #tablePagination_firstPage';
        var prevPageId = '#' + table.id + '+#tablePagination #tablePagination_prevPage';
        var nextPageId = '#' + table.id + '+#tablePagination #tablePagination_nextPage';
        var lastPageId = '#' + table.id + '+#tablePagination #tablePagination_lastPage';

        var possibleTableRows = $.makeArray($('tbody tr', table));
        var tableRows = $.grep(possibleTableRows, function (value, index) {
            return ($.inArray(value, defaults.ignoreRows) == -1);
        }, false)

        var numRows = tableRows.length
        var totalPages = resetTotalPages();
        var currPageNumber = (defaults.currPage > totalPages) ? 1 : defaults.currPage;
        if ($.inArray(defaults.rowsPerPage, defaults.optionsForRows) == -1)
            defaults.optionsForRows.push(defaults.rowsPerPage);


        function hideOtherPages(pageNum) {
            if (pageNum == 0 || pageNum > totalPages)
                return;
            var startIndex = (pageNum - 1) * defaults.rowsPerPage;
            var endIndex = (startIndex + defaults.rowsPerPage - 1);
            $(tableRows).show();
            for (var i = 0; i < tableRows.length; i++) {
                if (i < startIndex || i > endIndex) {
                    $(tableRows[i]).hide()
                }
            }
        }

        function resetTotalPages() {
            var preTotalPages = Math.round(numRows / defaults.rowsPerPage);
            var totalPages = (preTotalPages * defaults.rowsPerPage < numRows) ? preTotalPages + 1 : preTotalPages;
            if ($(totalPagesId).length > 0)
                $(totalPagesId).html(totalPages);
            return totalPages;
        }

        function resetCurrentPage(currPageNum) {
            if (currPageNum < 1 || currPageNum > totalPages)
                return;
            currPageNumber = currPageNum;
            hideOtherPages(currPageNumber);
            $(currPageId).val(currPageNumber)
        }

        function resetPerPageValues() {
            var isRowsPerPageMatched = false;
            var optsPerPage = defaults.optionsForRows;
            optsPerPage.sort();
            var perPageDropdown = $(rowsPerPageId)[0];
            perPageDropdown.length = 0;
            for (var i = 0; i < optsPerPage.length; i++) {
                if (optsPerPage[i] == defaults.rowsPerPage) {
                    perPageDropdown.options[i] = new Option(optsPerPage[i], optsPerPage[i], true, true);
                    isRowsPerPageMatched = true;
                }
                else {
                    perPageDropdown.options[i] = new Option(optsPerPage[i], optsPerPage[i]);
                }
            }
            if (!isRowsPerPageMatched) {
                defaults.optionsForRows == optsPerPage[0];
            }
        }

        function createPaginationElements() {
            var htmlBuffer = [];
            htmlBuffer.push("<div id='tablePagination'>");
            htmlBuffer.push("<span id='tablePagination_perPage'>");
            htmlBuffer.push("<select id='tablePagination_rowsPerPage'><option value='5'>5</option></select>");
            htmlBuffer.push("per page");
            htmlBuffer.push("</span>");
            htmlBuffer.push("<span id='tablePagination_paginater'>");
            htmlBuffer.push("<img id='tablePagination_firstPage' src='" + defaults.firstArrow + "'>");
            htmlBuffer.push("<img id='tablePagination_prevPage' src='" + defaults.prevArrow + "'>");
            htmlBuffer.push("Page");
            htmlBuffer.push("<input id='tablePagination_currPage' type='input' value='" + currPageNumber + "' size='1'>");
            htmlBuffer.push("of <span id='tablePagination_totalPages'>" + totalPages + "</span>");
            htmlBuffer.push("<img id='tablePagination_nextPage' src='" + defaults.nextArrow + "'>");
            htmlBuffer.push("<img id='tablePagination_lastPage' src='" + defaults.lastArrow + "'>");
            htmlBuffer.push("</span>");
            htmlBuffer.push("</div>");
            return htmlBuffer.join("").toString();
        }

        if ($(totalPagesId).length == 0) {
            $(this).after(createPaginationElements());
        }
        else {
            $('#tablePagination_currPage').val(currPageNumber);
        }
        resetPerPageValues();
        hideOtherPages(currPageNumber);

        $(firstPageId).bind('click', function (e) {
            resetCurrentPage(1)
        });

        $(prevPageId).bind('click', function (e) {
            resetCurrentPage(currPageNumber - 1)
        });

        $(nextPageId).bind('click', function (e) {
            resetCurrentPage(currPageNumber + 1)
        });

        $(lastPageId).bind('click', function (e) {
            resetCurrentPage(totalPages)
        });

        $(currPageId).bind('change', function (e) {
            resetCurrentPage(this.value)
        });

        $(rowsPerPageId).bind('change', function (e) {
            defaults.rowsPerPage = parseInt(this.value, 10);
            totalPages = resetTotalPages();
            resetCurrentPage(1)
        });

    })
};
```

})(jQuery);

The script is enabled client side with the following function:

```
       $('table').tablePagination({});
```

It also has some CSS as follows:

```
      #testTable { 
        width : 300px;
        margin-left: auto; 
        margin-right: auto; 
      }

       #tablePagination { 
        background-color:  Transparent; 
        font-size: 0.8em; 
        padding: 0px 5px; 
        height: 20px
      }

      #tablePagination_paginater { 
        margin-left: auto; 
        margin-right: auto;
      }

      #tablePagination img { 
        padding: 0px 2px; 
      }

      #tablePagination_perPage { 
        float: left; 
      }

      #tablePagination_paginater { 
        float: right; 
      }
```

I have tried a few things to apply this script to a certain gridviews:

Changing the clientside script to:

```
    $('#GridviewName').tablePagination({});
```

Also i have tried to make a few changes to the script file itself to try and get it to work as follows

```
        var possibleTableRows = $.makeArray($('.pagingclass tbody tr', table));
```

Here I have tried to specify a class and then I have added that CSS class to the gridview in order to apply the script to just that one gridview however it does not work.

I'm not entirely sure how I could do this or if it is possible at all. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the ID of the gridview

```
$('#<%=GridViewID.ClientID%>').tablePagination({});
```

When you use `$('table').tablePagination({});` you are targeting all tables on the page.  If you look at the HTML that's rendered from a gridview control, you'll see that it's similar to the ID you specify in the control, but not the same.  This is why you need to use the client ID designation instead of something like `$('#GridViewID').tablePagination({});`

Comment: Awesome! It worked. Thanks for the explanation also, that has saved me a whole bunch of trouble!